# How to use Rdp alternative shell/inital program in Windows 10(education)

Tags: windows-10, shell, remote-desktop

I am trying to launch an application using the "alternate shell" option of RDP to start a remote program. But it is not working and I am getting the whole session. Is that feature removed from the window 10? Or am I missing some properties? I simply edited the RDP file to change the alternative shell and executed the file.

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
screen mode id:i:1
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:1600
desktopheight:i:900
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,3,4192,-9,4992,591
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:192.168.0.103
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:c:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
drivestoredirect:s:
username:s:masood
```

I am trying to set an application as alternate shell. For example notepad++

Comment: What are you setting as the alternate shell? Try: add at the beginning of the .rdp file the lines: `enablecredsspsupport:i:0` and `authentication level:i:2`.

Comment: I am trying to set an application as alternative shell for example: alternate shell:s:c:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe. It can be any application

Comment: I have added but It's still not working

Comment: Does your command look like `alternate shell:s:c:\winnt\system32\notepad.exe`? Please post the .rdp file.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: any suggestions??

Comment: Try the alternative method, although it will apply to all RDP connections: Use Local Group Policy (gpedit.msc) at: `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment\Start a program on connection`.

Comment: Although this is not my requirement but I also tried this method before, It was also not working. I had set the application as remote app maybe it is because of that or windows 10 no longer support alternate shell.

Comment: RemoteApp already specifies the app to execute - you can't have two of them. For what you want, you should return to the classical method.